# Performance pros/cons for trigger.click vs .prop('checked', true)

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, triggers, click

I have a simple reset button that needs to check a radio button. Wondering which is the best approach:

```
$("#styleWidthWide").trigger('click');
```

**or**

```
$("#styleWidthWide").prop('checked', true);
```

Many thanks for insight.

Comment: In your context, click trigger in radio button will toggle value, when prop('checked', true) will setting true value. In this case, this lines incomparable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're entirely different, so performance questions are moot.

`.trigger()` will emulate a click on the element, and invoke any jQuery handlers on it or any of its ancestors *(unless propagation is stopped)*.

Given your example, you're toggling the value unless there's a handler that overrides it.

---

`.prop()` simply sets the property. In your example, you're setting the value to `true` instead of toggling.

---

If performance is truly a concern, and all you need is to set the property, then use native methods.

```
document.getElementById("styleWidthWide").checked = true;
```

This will be much faster than either jQuery solution. However, it will likely not be a perceptible difference. All depends on the rest of the code.

http://jsperf.com/trigger-vs-prop/2

Answer (score 1):

You can use jsperf for that kind of test: http://jsperf.com/trigger-vs-prop

On my browser (Firefox 28) the `trigger()` version is 95% slower than the `prop()` version

Comment: Didn't know about jsperf... thanks for sharing about such a relevant and helpful resource.

Comment: No problem ;) I discovered it since a few months only and I find it extremely helpful too.